# Defining methods

Tags: javascript, closures

What does the method `incorrect` not work?

```js
var myFunction = {}
myFunction.init = function() {
 myFunction.correct = function() {
 }
 function incorrect() {
 }
}
myFunction.init()
myFunction.correct()
myFunction.incorrect() // This doesn't work
```

Comment: What would you *expect* it to do? If anything, if your apparently present assumption would hold at all, it should show up as `myFunction.init.incorrect`. But of course it doesn't even do that, because it's just a locally scoped function not exposed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'incorrect' is not a method of myFunction, only a function within myFunction's 'init' method.

'correct' has been set as a property/method, which is why it works and 'incorrect' does not.

Comment: Can I use `this.correct` instead of `myFunction.correct`?

Comment: @PhillipSenn `this.correct()` would only be accessible by `myFunction.init.correct()`, because it was set inside the `init` property of `myFunction`.